# Excel VBA: How to remove substrings from a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell value like this:

```
This is a <"string">string, It should be <"changed">changed to <"a"> a number.
```

There are some words repeated in this part `<"  ">`.

I want use Excel VBA to change the cell value to:

```
This is a string, It should be changed to a number.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend the use of [Regular Expressions (RegEx)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) to remove the unwanted substrings.

Comment: Will the <" "> actually be there? Or are you trying to prevent having the same word in a row twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the text in cell A1, then try this code

```
Sub DelDoubleString()
Dim Text As String, Text2Replace As String, NewText As String
On Error Resume Next        'Optional, in case there's no double string to be deleted
Text = Cells(1, 1)

Do
    Text2Replace = Mid$(Text, InStr(Text, "<"), InStr(Text, ">") - InStr(Text, "<") + 1)
    NewText = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Text, Text2Replace, vbNullString)
    Text = NewText
Loop Until InStr(NewText, "<") = 0

Cells(1, 1) = NewText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the suggestion to use regular expressions, here's an example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveByRegexWithLateBinding()

    Dim strIn As String
    Dim strOut As String
    Dim objRegex As Object

    'input
    strIn = "This is a <""string"">string, It should be <""changed"">changed to <""a""> a number."
    Debug.Print "Input:" & vbCr & strIn

    'create and apply regex
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegex.Pattern = "<""[^<>""]*"">"
    objRegex.Global = True
    strOut = objRegex.Replace(strIn, "")

    'test output
    Debug.Print "Output:" & vbCr & strOut

End Sub
```

Produces this output:

```
Input:
This is a <"string">string, It should be <"changed">changed to <"a"> a number.
Output:
This is a string, It should be changed to  a number.
```

Diagram of regular expression:

[image]

Which can be explained as finding a string that:

- begins with `<"`
- contains anything apart from the characters `<`, `>` and `"`
- ends with `">`

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier - regexes are a steep learning curve, but it is worth the effort. The regex in my answer basically says match anything in `<"` and `">` except the characters `<` `>` and `"`. The regex looks a bit more complicated than it needs to because of the doubled `""` in the pattern which are required because VBA uses `"` for strings and the pattern also needs `"` in its value. The pattern is actually `<"[^<>"]*">` without this complication. You can try it http://www.regex101.com

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells containing your text and run this short macro:

```
Sub Kleanup()
    Dim d As Range, s As String, rng As Range
    Dim gather As Boolean, L As Long, DQ As String
    Dim i As Long, s2 As String, CH As String

    Set rng = Selection
    DQ = Chr(34)

    For Each r In rng
        s = Replace(r.Text, "<" & DQ, Chr(1))
        s = Replace(s, DQ & ">", Chr(2))
        gather = True
        L = Len(s)
        s2 = ""
        For i = 1 To L
            CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
            If CH = Chr(1) Then gather = False
            If CH = Chr(2) Then gather = True
            If gather And CH <> Chr(2) Then s2 = s2 & CH
        Next i
        r.Value = s2
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

U can Use Replace function

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Replace(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value, "String", "Number")
```

Comment: That's not what she's asking at all.